# different kinds of cells in the same column

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn

I need to render a datagrid with different kinds of cells in the same column. For example, I have a datagrid with a column "name" and a column "value". Depending on the "type" of my record, I would have different cells in the column "value" like a combobox or a simple textfield. and I don't really see how to do that programmatically... I don't know if the datagrid is the best choice. Any hint?

I'm using asp.net/vb.net with framework 3.5

Comment: This would suggest to me either a bad data structure or a messy/inconsistent user interface - just an observation

Comment: I know I agree with you ... it's a "messy/inconsistent user interface" but now I don't have any choice ... that's the way I have to do it ...

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the user control, where you pass the "type" to the user control and the user control will handle the type of control to show or generate.