# DataGrid: Same Column, Different Input Methods?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I am not a WPF expert. After tinkering for a few projects, this is my first full-fleged attempt. It isn't as simple as "Windows Forms", but the flexibility more than makes up for it!

I have an entity that houses all application settings. The user interfaces with them via a DatGrid. The Column is TextBox, but the content could be anything that a string can represent (text/string, date, integer, double, etc.).

To make things very easy for the user, and less bug-prone, I'd like to offer a [User?] Control that is appropriate for the data to be inserted (fictional approach below, might be impossible/impractical... consider it *pseudo-code-ish*):

- In a not visible column/attribute of the instance/entity I would specify "date"/"DatePicker", drop-down, etc.
- The "value" column in the DataGrid would hold/accept the setting for that row.
- If a date is involved, a datepicker would be made available for that row of the setting column.
- A TextBox would look like a normal DataGrid cell... You get the idea...
- I already have all the CRUD operations resolved, all the way back to the DB (that took a while to figure out, but with DBContext/Entities I am now a huge convert to WPF/EF6!
- This app is in VB (VS2012Ult), but since I write in C# as well, I have no trouble converting any sample/example code.

disclaimer: This may seem clunky/silly as an approach, but users are notorious at entering things the wrong way, in the wrong format, etc. This approach is intended for non techies/coders to be able to reliably use the app without calling helpdesk as often.

note: A long time ago, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496470/different-kinds-of-cells-in-the-same-column) asked an extremely similar, if not identical, question. I am asking to see what has improved since then. I am not a WPF expert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're basically looking for a [`PropertyGrid`](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PropertyGrid), similar to this:

[image]

**1 - Easy way out:** Use the (free, open source) Extended WPF toolkit linked above.

**2 - Hard way out:**

Build it yourself so that you can learn a lot of beautiful WPF and adapt it to your specific needs.

Use an [`ItemsControl`](http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/) and several [`DataTemplate`](http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/01/03/itemscontrol-d-is-for-datatemplate/)s (one for each Data Type). Start by reading the ItemsControl link.